# How much time does it normally take to get certificate of participation in a conference?

Tags: conference

I participated in a conference (oral presentation), It is my first conference ever as I am in my first year of PhD. The conference ended 3 weeks agp now and they still did not send me any certificate of attendance/participation. How much time does it normally take to get certificate of participation in a conference?

Note : the conference was five days long (Monday to Friday, about 10 partcipants each day).

Comment: I don't believe I ever got a certificate of participation at any conference I went to. Do you need it for travel reimbursement or something like that?

Comment: I never heard of such, actually.

Comment: Did you request it? If you didn't request it, then this probably won't happen until then.

Comment: Yes I actually need it for administrative issues. However I thought that it is given without requesting it. Especially, a lot of conferences I saw mention that certificates of attendance will be given ! Thank you all for the feedback. I think I will request it explicitly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not all conferences provide a certificate of participation. Some will provide such documents only by request. Many participants would not need such certificates at all, so it often makes sense not to provide them by default.

If you require a certificate of participation, write to conference organisers and ask for it.

Comment: Maybe worth clarifying that the only real need would be for reimbursement of conference/travel expenses if a policy requires it. No need for a certificate for, say, adding a presentation to your CV.

Comment: I've never seen the certificate provided by default.  Always on request.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I have seen certificates provided by default at different conferences in different countries. I have also seen them provided by request.